# bootstrap, row into navbar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Is it possible to turn a col into a navbar?

I've already got a top navbar. But I'd like for this one below to turn into a navbar for md and lower screens.

```
<div class="row" id="bottomInfoRow">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <ul class="list-inline">
                <li>1</li>
                <li>2</li>
                <li>3</li>
                <li>4</li>
                <li>5</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: It's not clear at all what you're trying to accomplish and if there is other code (HTML/CSS/JS) related to this you should post everything as a working example in a Snippet/jsFiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honestly, maybe this is what you're looking for but it really isn't clear as far as functionality goes but it's pretty simple.

The example uses columns in conjunction with the `navbar-nav` class to while using CSS to adjust a custom `navbar` class that everything is enclosed in.

(**Most of the CSS is for a better display in general and is not neccessary)

See working example Snippet at Full Page.

```css
.navbar.nav-lower {
  background: #eee;
  margin-top: -20px;
  border-radius: 0;
  border: none;
  text-align: center;
}
.navbar.nav-lower .navbar-nav {
  float: none;
}
.navbar.nav-lower .navbar-nav > li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
  margin: 0 -5px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.navbar.nav-lower .navbar-toggle,
.navbar.nav-lower .navbar-toggle:hover,
.navbar.nav-lower .navbar-toggle:focus {
  border: none;
  background: none;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar.nav-lower {
    background: none;
  }
  .navbar.nav-lower .navbrand-hidden {
    display: none;
  }
}
/**Use This rule to Display the Links as Block**/

/*@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .navbar.nav-lower .navbar-nav > li {
        display: block;
        text-align: left;
        width: 100%;
    }
}*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-top" aria-expanded="false"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>

      </button> <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>

    </div>
    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-top">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a>

        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default nav-lower">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-bottom" aria-expanded="false"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>

      </button><a class="navbar-brand navbrand-hidden" href="#">Collapse Nav</a>

    </div>
    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-bottom">
      <div class="row" id="bottomInfoRow">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#">Link</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a>

            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#">Link</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a>

            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#">Link</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a>

            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks alot, this is suddenly in the right direction. I'll look through the code and make adjustments accordingly. Thanks alot!

Comment: No problem and glad I could help.

Comment: @vanburen  i did exactly like this, however, i am unable to make the lower navbar full screen width. How can I make this navbar go full width just like the top one ?

Answer (score 0):

No. It is not possible to have a col as a nav.

BUT, you can have multiple navbars on one page. Here is an example:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="container-fluid nooverflow" role="main">
      <div class="site-canvas row">
        <div class="masthead">
          <div class="row blue dfs-header">
            <div class="col-xs-3">
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="{!$Page.CP_COM_Home}" style="float:none;">
                <i class="icon-ui" style="font-size:74px;position:relative;top:12px;"></i>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
              <div class="dfs-header-text">
                <span>
                  Financial Services<sup>&#8482;</sup>
                </span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-offset-1 col-md-2">
              <ul id="logged">
                <li class="dropdown" id="logged-user">
                  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    <i class="icon-small-useraccount"> </i>
                    <apex:outputtext value="{!CustomerPortalUserName}"></apex:outputtext>
                    <span class="caret"></span>
                  </a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li>
                      <a href="{!$Site.Prefix}/secur/logout.jsp?retUrl=https://www.google.com">Logout</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#">User Option 2</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="{!$Page.CP_COM_ChangeCurrentPassword}">Change Password</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown" id="logged-co">
                  <apex:form >
                    <apex:selectlist value="{!SelectedCCAN}" size="1">
                      <apex:actionsupport action="{!UpdateSelectedCompany}" event="onchange" />
                      <apex:selectoptions value="{!CustomerCCANS}" />
                    </apex:selectlist>
                  </apex:form>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="header-shim"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Navigation under header-->
        <div class="row blue">
          <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-10">
            <nav class="navbar">
              <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified " id="nav-links">
                <li>
                  <a href="{!$Page.CP_COM_ContractsList}">Contracts</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="{!$Page.CP_COM_AssetDetails}">Asset Details</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="{!$Page.CP_COM_ProductInformation}">Product Information</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="{!$Page.CP_COM_MyDocuments}">My Documents</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="{!$Page.CP_COM_MainCustomerCare}">Contact Customer Care</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="{!$Page.CP_COM_Admin}">Admin</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </nav>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Don't get confused by the URLFOR or Apex tags because this came out of a Saleforce app. Here we use stacking two navbars on top of each other. You can style them however you like. They do not have to be in the same row, column, or container. Control the positioning with css.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But my ul is in-line. I were looking for something that just could turn an ordinary ul in-line list to a navbar once it got rescaled to lesser widths